# 'No main manifest attribute' while running JAR file built with Gradle

Tags: java, jar, gradle, manifest, program-entry-point

I wrote a small Java application using Gradle to build it. The app comes from [this tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/gs/gradle/) and contains 2 classes: HelloWorld (the main class) and Greeter. The `build.gradle` file contains 2 sections (and others, which are currently irrelevant):

```
apply plugin: 'application'
mainClassName = 'hello.HelloWorld'
```

and

```
dependencies {
compile "joda-time:joda-time:2.2"
}
```

(this is necessary, because the HelloWorld class imports org.joda.time.LocalTime class).
I can build the app with `gradle build` and run it with `gradle run`. Everything is OK and I get the result. However, when I try to run it with `java -jar HelloWorld.jar`, I get the error `No main manifest attribute`. One of solutions found on StackOverflow suggested running the file as

```
java -cp HelloWorld.jar hello.HelloWorld
```

or

```
java -cp HelloWorld.jar HelloWorld
```

The first one returns `Could not find or load main class HelloWorld`, the second one returns `java.lang.NotClassDefFoundError" org/joda/time/LocalTime`. The JAR archive contains following files:

```
  0 Mon Jul 06 13:13:46 CEST 2015 META-INF/
 25 Mon Jul 06 13:13:46 CEST 2015 META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
  0 Mon Jul 06 13:13:46 CEST 2015 hello/
369 Mon Jul 06 13:13:46 CEST 2015 hello/Greeter.class
988 Mon Jul 06 13:13:46 CEST 2015 hello/HelloWorld.class
```

I have no idea why gradle doesn't put information about main class into the manifest file. Do you have any suggestions? The code comes directly from the tutorial so it should be OK, but it's not. I repeat that running the app via gradle makes no issues.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gradle- no main manifest attribute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32567167/gradle-no-main-manifest-attribute)

Answer (score 2):

This error occurs because `org.joda.time.LocalTime` is not added to classpath while running `hello.HelloWorld`.

1. It can be run with classpath set with: `gradle run`
2. You can include this dependency in the jar, using [this](https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow) plugin.
3. Or prepare a distribution with `distZip` task, unzip it and use sh or bat script to run the prepared artifact.