# Gradle - no main manifest attribute

Tags: java, gradle, jar

I'm building a JAR file with Gradle. When I try to run it I get the following error

> no main manifest attribute, in RxJavaDemo.jar

I tried manipulating the `manifest` property but I think I'm forgetting to add the dependencies or something to it. What exactly am I doing wrong?

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'application'

mainClassName = 'demo.MainDashboard'

dependencies {
    compile files ("H:/Processes/Development/libraries/hikari-cp/HikariCP-2.4.1.jar")
    compile files ("H:/Processes/Development/libraries/controls-fx/controlsfx.jar")
    compile files ("H:/Processes/Development/libraries/database_connections/sqlite-jdbc-3.8.6.jar")
    compile files ("H:/Processes/Development/libraries/guava/guava-18.0.jar")
    compile files ("H:/Processes/Development/libraries/rxjava/rxjava-1.0.12.jar")
    compile files ("H:/Processes/Development/libraries/rxjava-extras/rxjava-extras-0.5.15.jar")
    compile files ("H:/Processes/Development/libraries/rxjavafx/RxJavaFX-1.0.0-RC1-SNAPSHOT.jar")
    compile files ("H:/Processes/Development/libraries/rxjavaguava/rxjava-guava-1.0.3.jar")
    compile files ("H:/Processes/Development/libraries/rxjava-jdbc/rxjava-jdbc-0.6.3.jar")
    compile files ("H:/Processes/Development/libraries/slf4j/slf4j-api-1.7.12.jar")
    compile files ("H:/Processes/Development/libraries/tom-commons/tom-commons.jar")
}

sourceSets {
    main.java.srcDir "src/main/java"
    main.resources.srcDir "src/main/resources"
}

jar { 
    manifest {
    attributes(
        "Class-Path": configurations.compile.collect { it.getName() }.join(' '))
    }
    from configurations.compile.collect { entry -> zipTree(entry) }
}
```

Answer (score 193, accepted):

Try to change your manifest attributes like:

```
jar {
  manifest {
    attributes(
      'Class-Path': configurations.compile.collect { it.getName() }.join(' '),
      'Main-Class': 'hello.HelloWorld'
    )
  }
}
```

And then just change `'hello.helloWorld'` to `'<your packagename>.<the name of your Main class>'` (where your Main class has a main method). In this case, you make in your manifest an attribute, which point to this class, then a jar is running.

Comment: @Stanislav 'Main-Class' value is the main class? What are hello and helloWorld in your example?

Comment: @DanielaMaia it's just a full qualified class name, sure it has to be written as hello.HelloWorld, where hello is the package where the HelloWorld class is located

Comment: I needed to remove the `collect {}` portion to get it to work for me. Your code assumes that all dependencies are in the same folder as your main class.

Comment: @AutonomousApps How exactly did you do that?

Comment: It works, but I only add 'Main-Class' attribute.

Comment: The lastest Gradle version has replaced `compile`. Instead use:
`'Class-Path': configurations.runtimeClasspath.files.collect { it.getName() }.join(' ')`

Comment: `Build failed with an exception: Could not get unknown property 'compile' for configuration container`

Comment: Is this still correct? You can't use application.main-class? Also why does gradle init do it the other way then?

Answer (score 37):

To make the `jar` file executable (so that the `java -jar` command works), specify the `Main-Class` attribute in `MANIFEST.MF`.

In Gradle, you can do it by configuring the `jar` task.

- for **Groovy** DSL see these answers ([[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32567525/6486622), [[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43088446/6486622))
- for **Kotlin** DSL you can use the following code snippet:

```kotlin
tasks.withType<Jar> {
    manifest {
        attributes["Main-Class"] = "com.caco3.Main"
    }
}
```

#### Why `mainClassName` does not work as expected?

Or why `mainClassName` does not specify the attribute in the manifest?

The `mainClassName` property comes from the [`application` plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/application_plugin.html). The plugin:

> makes it easy to **start the application locally** during development, and to *package* the application as a **TAR** and/or **ZIP** *including operating system specific start scripts*.

*So the `application` plugin does not aim at producing executable `jar`s*

When a `mainClassName` property set, then:

1. `$ ./gradlew run` will launch the `main` method in the class specified in the attribute
2. the `zip`/`tar` archive built using `distZip`/`distTar` tasks will contain a script, which will launch the `main` method of the specified previously class.

Here is the line of shell script setting the main class:

```
$ grep Main2 gradletest
eval set -- $DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS $JAVA_OPTS $GRADLETEST_OPTS -classpath "\"$CLASSPATH\"" com.caco3.gradletest.Main2 "$APP_ARGS"
```

Comment: I get that the application plugin doesn't have a goal of creating a runnable jar, but it's still annoying that we have to do these extra steps in Gradle all the time for a runnable jar. It should have everything it needs for a manifest...

Comment: Although I suppose the reason is, your jar will be missing dependencies so it's not usually runnable anyway. :)

Answer (score 5):

To complement [Denis Zavedeev answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63767408/8583692), here are more ways for [Kotlin DSL](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/kotlin_dsl.html) (build.gradle.kts):

```kotlin
tasks.jar {
    manifest.attributes["Main-Class"] = "com.example.MyMainClass"
}
```

Another notation:

```kotlin
tasks.jar {
    manifest {
        attributes["Main-Class"] = "com.example.MyMainClass"
    }
}
```

Side note: to create a runnable fat JAR (also called uber JAR), see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70864141/8583692).

Comment: Starting with Gradle `8.x` somehow array access for attributes is unavailable.

Comment: @YaMiN Are you sure? I tried both of the above code snippets right now with Gradle 8.0 and it seemed to work with no problem.

Comment: Yeah I'm sure. I don't know why but after upgrading to Gradle 8.0.2 it gives me `No set method providing array access` error, however, the project compiles.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW - I used the following jar task to assemble all my compile dependencies into the jar file, and used the above recommendation to get the class-path properly set

```
apply plugin: 'java-library'

jar {
  manifest {
    attributes(
      'Class-Path': configurations.compile.collect { it.getName() }.join(' '),
      'Main-Class': 'your.main.class.goes.here'
    )
  }

  // You can reference any part of the dependency configurations,
  // and you can have as many from statements as you need
  from configurations.compile  
  // I just copied them into the top of the jar, so it looks like the eclipse exported 
  // runnable jar, but you could designate a lib directory, and reference that in the 
  // classpath as "lib/$it.name" instead of it.getName()
  into ''   
}
```