# How do I create my procfile file for heroku?

Tags: java, heroku, intellij-idea, gradle, procfile

I'm trying to use Heroku with Java, I have this directory structure and I'm using IntelliJ:

```
target
  com
    x
     y
      Main.java
```

in the procfile:

```
web: java -cp target/classes/;target/dependency/* com.x.y.Main
```

When I try `heroku local web` I get " `Could not find or load main class com.x.y.Main` "

However, it is there. I'm using Windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java classpath separator is platform dependent, `;` for Windows and `:` for Unix.

If you are trying to run `heroku local` on Windows, your command will fail with exactly the message you posted. Replacing it with:

`web: java -cp target/classes/;target/dependency/* com.x.y.Main`

will make it run on Windows.

If you get this error with the app deployed in the cloud (which is Unix), then there is no `com.x.y.Main` class in the `target/classes` directory. You can verify that by running `heroku run bash` followed by `ls -lR` and checking the directory/files layout on the server.

If you run on Windows ensure to run `mvn clean install` to compile the sources into `target/classes` directory.

For Gradle based projects you would need to adjust the classpath since it uses the different layout (`build/classes`) or the jar file in `build/libs`, [see the guide for the details](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-gradle-apps-on-heroku):

`web: java -jar build/libs/myprojectname-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar`

To make it work in cloud and on Windows without changing Procfile every time, create `Procfile.windows` with `web: java -cp target/classes/;target/dependency/* com.x.y.Main` and start the app using `heroku local web -f Procfile.windows` command locally.

Comment: Check my updated post. I updated my procfile but I'm still getting the error

Comment: @AbAppletic How exactly do you run the app, locally or in cloud, what command is used? Can you provide the list of files in `target/classes`?

Comment: `heroku local web`

Comment: I don't have a `classes` folder in target

Comment: That is the case of the problem then, `mvn clean install` should produce the `.class` files there.

Comment: I'm using Gradle, not maven

Comment: Even when I run `gradlew clean install` no files are created in the `target` directory

Comment: Gradle probably has different layout, see where the classes are produced and adjust your classpath, in my testing I was using Maven.

Comment: I found it. They're generated in build/classes

Comment: Great, I've updated the answer to cover all possible cases, hope it works for you now or at least you know where to look.

Comment: So now that I know where they are, what do I do?

Comment: You need to adjust the classpath to include the classes and dependencies. If you don't have target folder, then your dependencies are also elsewhere. The `-cp` should list everything required to start the app. Adjust the locations depending on the app requirements.

Comment: Is dependecy-cache the dependency folder?

Comment: it is also in `build`

Comment: Why don't you just use the final jar with all the dependencies? Does gradle produce one? `web: java -jar /path/to/jar.jar`

Comment: Where would I find that?

Comment: Should be in `build/libs`, see https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-gradle-apps-on-heroku for the sample.

Comment: Error: Unable to access jarfile /build/libs/myprojectname-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar

Comment: Do you have `build/libs/myprojectname-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar` file? What's your `Procfile` now?

Comment: `web: java -jar /build/libs/myprojectname-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar` is my  procfile. I'm sure I have the jar in there

Comment: You have an extra slash in the start of the path, as you can see from the example, the slash is not used, try this: `web: java -jar build/libs/myprojectname-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar`

Comment: Now I get this:  `no main manifest attribute, in build/libs/myprojectname-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar`

Comment: Your jar file doesn't specify the entry point (the main class) in its Manifest. You either need to adjust `build.gradle` to produce the jar with the main class in the manifest or adjust the Procfile to specify the main class. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5474748/104891) for details.

Comment: Exactly what do I add to the build.gradle to produce the jar with the main class in the manifest?

Comment: I understood what I need to do, but what do i edit? Where is this manifest located?

Comment: You edit `build.gradle` file and it generates the jar with the manifest for you.

Comment: I understand, but where is the manifest generated so I can edit it?

Comment: It's generated inside the jar file. `file.jar/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF`. You are not supposed to edit it manually, rather let Gradle generate it.

Comment: If i'm not supposed to edit it manually, then how do I change it?

Comment: You change `build.gradle` file which in turn affects the Manifest file that is generated by Gradle.

Comment: So what do i change the build.gradle? I can't see anything related to the manifest there

Comment: It would be much easier to help you if you share your complete project in its current state. As you can see in the [linked answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32567525/104891), you add the directive for jar file to specify the main class attribute in the generated jar/manifest.

Comment: I really don't know what you mean by "add the directinve for jar file to specify...".

Comment: I'll just [refer you to the official Gradle documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#sec:jar) so that you study it yourself. Sorry, but I can't explain it any better.