# Gradle Output Jar has no Main-Class

Tags: java, gradle, jar

I have the following simple build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'application'
apply plugin: 'java'

mainClassName = 'com.kurtis.HelloGradle'
```

And the following single java file located at `src/main/java/com/kurtis/HelloGradle.java`:

```
package com.kurtis;

public class HelloGradle {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Hello gradle");
    }

}
```

However, if I run `gradle build` I get a jar in the `build/lib` directory that has no main class set. It's manifest file has no `Main-Class` entry. Why is this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gradle- no main manifest attribute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32567167/gradle-no-main-manifest-attribute)

Comment: Have you read the docs: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/application_plugin.html ?

Comment: @Opal yep, I've been reading those.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's due to the way application plugin works. `mainClassName` is a property used by `application` plugin, when it creates an executable jar, it doesn't need to have a `Main-Class` in the manifest, since it doesn't use it.

If you need to have a `Main-Class` in your jar, then you have to provide it vie `jar` configuration of the `java` plugin as follows:

```
jar {
  manifest {
    attributes(
      'Main-Class': 'com.kurtis.HelloGradle'
    )
  }
}
```

Otherwise, just use an executable, which is generated by application plugin, whether via `run` task or via distributions it can create for you, with scripts to run your application and all it's dependencies.

Comment: This was a great explanation. Cleared up a lot of things for me. Thanks!

Comment: thanks! No I'm wondering what I'd need the application plugin for.. I'll just use the java plugin and this. Sufficient to start it with java -jar x.jar

Comment: Would be nice to point out that, nowadays, if you are using the `application` plugin and correctly setting `mainClassName`, there is no need to specify `Main-Class` inside `jar`'s manifest attributes.