# GKE gradle no main manifest attribute

Tags: java, gradle, google-kubernetes-engine

Hello i am testing GKE features and i created gradle java 17 init application, while deployment i have issue with manifest so i generated manually to artifact to resources :

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: pl.kathelan.mdbackend.MdBackendApplication
```

here is my gradle build :

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.7.3'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.13.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'pl.kathelan'
version = '0.0.1'
sourceCompatibility = '17'

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
jar {
    manifest {
        attributes(
                "Class-Path": configurations.runtimeClasspath .collect { it.getName() }.join(' '))
    }
}

sourceSets.main.resources.srcDirs = [ "src/" ]
```

i have tried this solution [Gradle - no main manifest attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32567167/gradle-no-main-manifest-attribute) , but for me was exception class no found. Looking for any help thanks.

Answer (score 0):

found mistake in docker file :

```
ENV ARTIFACT_NAME=md-backend-0.0.1.jar
```

was md-backend-0.0.1-plain.jar